# どうしてfinalizeを使うべきではないのですか？

Tags: java

「Javaのfinalizeによるクリーンアップ処理の実装は行うべきではない」と教わったのですが、なぜそうなのでしょう？
また、finalizeを使わずに同じようなことをすることはできるのでしょうか？

Comment: 書籍Effective Javaでも「finalizerは避ける」とされていますね。原著の[Item 7: Avoid finalizers が公開](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1216151&seqNum=7)されていました。

Answer (score 15):

コメントで教えていただいたところにとても良く書いてあったので、自分でまとめます。

finalizeはいつ呼ばれるかわからないし、呼ばれないかもしれない。JVMの実装にも依存するのでコードの可搬性が失われる。また、finalizeはファイナライズスレッドで実行されるが、ここで例外が発生してもエラーにはならず、オブジェクトが中途半端な状態でメモリに残る可能性がある。
だから、そんな不安定な処理に依存する処理は書くべきではない。

Answer (score 7):

さまざまなブログや記事がありますが、一番詳細に書かれているのはJPCertのこちらのページでしょうか。

https://www.jpcert.or.jp/java-rules/met12-j.html

特に気になるところとしては、

- ファイナライザの実行は、オブジェクトが到達不能になった後、どれだけ延期されるか分からない。
- JVMは、到達不能なオブジェクトのファイナライザを実行せずに終了するかもしれない。つまり、ファイナライザメソッドにおいて(オブジェクトの)重要な永続的状態を更新しようとしても、警告なしに失敗するかもしれない。→つまりファイルのロックや接続プールが残ったままの可能性がある。

…と、あとは様々な欠点が書かれており、独自に実装すべきではない、とも強く書かれています。

finalyzeの代替手段とは言えませんが、取得したリソースの開放は適切に行う（残しっぱなしにしない、例外ハンドリングを忘れない）ことでしょうか。